# Does postgresql logical replication use encryption?

Tags: postgresql, replication

**Does postgresql logical replication use encryption?** I am referring to native not pglogical. I can't find any documentation on how this works if I want to replicate over the internet.

Thanks!

I have setup replication using `CREATE PUBLICATION` and `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION` as described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html
But it has no information on encryption.

Comment: Yes, use SSL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no different than any other connection, just specify the parameters you want.  For example:

```
 create subscription sub CONNECTION 'host=example.com sslmode=verify-full' publication pub;
```